# Compiling Haskell module to Javascript using ghcjs

Tags: haskell, ghcjs

Is it possible to compile a Haskell module to JS using `ghcjs`? I played with it, but it seems it requires `main` function to be defined before it would generate JS. A toy code below:

```
module Test where

add :: Int -> Int -> Int
add x y = x + y
```

I can't figure out how to compile it to JS using `ghcjs`. It will compile only .hi and .o files if main function is not defined. If I can figure out a way to compile it to JS (with appropriate `Z-encoded` function name, and a corresponding JS object, like what we have in `FFI` for C), then I could use more powerful Haskell libraries like `unordered-containers` and `vector` to implement some algorithm, compile to JS, and use in `Elm` through JS FFI.

`Fay` seems to be capable of doing it. I will like to investigate it for `ghcjs` first.

Comment: What’s your precise command line?

Comment: @JoachimBreitner, ` ghcjs Test.hs` where Test.hs is above code. ghcjs claims it is "generating JavaScript" but I don't see any js code. I am using version 0.1.0.

Comment: Have you tried `ghcjs -c Test.hs`? Does that work better?

Comment: @JoachimBreitner, adding `-c` option doesn't make any difference either.

Comment: Fay is; A proper subset of Haskell that compiles to JavaScript. https://github.com/faylang/fay/wiki

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just asked the ghcjs author (luite) in IRC, and he said, "there is no good way yet to directly export a library."

He does seem very interested in supporting that capability, though, so I'm hoping, and optimistic that this will change in the near future. The place to watch this issue is [the ticket requesting this feature on github](https://github.com/ghcjs/ghcjs/issues/194).

Comment: but what is the status of this as or 2015 Apr?

Comment: The ticket hasn't been updated since February 2015, and it's still open, so looks like it isn't done yet. ghcjs development is still very active (with commits in the last day) so I'm still optimistic on having this feature in t he future.